# System-wide tweak of Adwaita theme to highlight the active tab in Firefox?

Tags: 20.04, firefox, themes

I'm running Firefox 81.0 on Ubuntu 20.04, and the default theme is Adwaita, where the active tab (#EAEBE9) is almost the same color as the inactive tabs(#E7E8E6):

[image: Adwaita theme]

However, when I switch to e.g. the Ambiance theme, there is a sharp contrast between the color of the active tab (#F4F3F2) and the color of the inactive tabs (#504F47):

[image: Ambiance theme]

My usual workaround has been to install a custom theme, such as [Adwaita Mix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adwaita-mix/). However, I'm looking for something system-wide that works on the default theme and doesn't require changing the browser profile. Here's my questions:

1. How can I make a system-wide tweak to the Adwaita theme to show a contrast between the active tab and the inactive tab?

   In Firefox's [custom themes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/theme), these would be called `toolbar` and `frame`/`frame_inactive`, but I'm not sure what the GTK+ equivalent is. I peeked at `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and saw this:

   ```
    /* Adwaita is now part of GTK+ 3, this file is no longer used */
   ```

   but presumably the theme can still be modified somehow without recompiling `libgtk-3-0`, right?
2. Is this an intentional design choice or is there a place I should file an issue to fix this?

   I didn't see anything already filed in the [Adwaita issue tracker](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/tree/master/gtk/theme/Adwaita) or in the [Firefox issue tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/home).

Comment: i wont post this as an answer because it does not answer your question... but I am using Yaru(on Metacity... [and even Ambiant-MATE on MATE for that matter])... and my firefox (on both) looks exactly like your desired result... I have not made any tweaks (at least I dont think I have). I'm not much of a themer.

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver I have added a answer below; Hope it works in your case;  If it doesn't - tell me what went wrong, //Wishes

Comment: @NatanielM.Beaver is it Ok if we create a new theme? I mean instead of Adwaita (Default), Create our own theme based on Adwaita (Default) as ADW_MOD (Adwaita Modified) ? Or you dont want to change the default theme and still want to apply the changes?

Comment: @UnKNOWn Changing to another theme like Ambiance already works. I'd prefer to selectively override the default theme, although if that's not possible I'd relax the "system-wide" to an addition to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` that would at least be "user-wide". I'd also accept a patch for [`Adwaita/_common.scss`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/974ce500d65dd993bed3fc9248c695ccc2120856/gtk/theme/Adwaita/_common.scss) that could be sent upstream. ;-)

Comment: keeping the Adwaita theme, I could make it this way which is opposite to your question.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRCI5.png we can change what ever color we want in place of lightblue..

Comment: @UnKNOWn Pretty close; any way to have different text colors in the active/inactive tabs?

Comment: @UnKNOWn Yes, that's OK; it's not ideal but a reasonable modification given the constraints we're working with. I'm mostly interested in what changes to Adwaita would be necessary, particularly in a way that can go upstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no way to change the tab colors individually (did not find any documentation for the style class for firefox tab's only, in my research)

Also the link provided by you in Question have this below image, nowhere it is mentioned colors for the individual tabs..

[image]

This link https://color.firefox.com/ shows different components that can be customized, this also indicates no way to change individual tab colors..

In this scenario, the closest we can achieve is from below workaround..

create a theme folder with required directories and text file in system files named "ADW_MOD" (Adwaita Modified) with below command

```
sudo install -D /dev/null /usr/share/themes/ADW_MOD/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

open the css file with below command

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/themes/ADW_MOD/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

copy paste below content, save the file & close..

```
@import url("resource:///org/gtk/libgtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained.css");

#MozillaGtkWidget .menubar,
#MozillaGtkWidget menubar {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: blue;
}
```

Choose the gtk-theme `ADW_MOD` from gnome-tweaks or via command line,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "ADW_MOD"
```

you can modify the colors from above content or if you find documentation for GTK theme for fire fox specifying style class, you can modify the above content for more customizations..

[image]